# Why does sort() doesn't work for vector of pair

Tags: c++, vector, std-pair

I've been trying to sort the vector of pair by the second value but it shows some error in this code.

```
class Solution{
public:
bool sec(const pair<int,int>&p1,const pair<int,int>&p2)
{
    return (p1.second<p2.second);
}   
void print(){
    vector<pair<int,int>>v={{1,5},{2,4},{4,3},{7,8}};
    sort(v.begin(),v.end(),sec);
    for(auto i:v)
    {
        cout<<i.first<<" "<<i.second;
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

};

Comment: whats the error

Comment: The specific problem is that `sec` is a member-function, and std::sort doesn't know how to call member functions. You can fix this by either moving `sec` outside the class, or by making it a `static` member.

Comment: Or by passing a lambda function that does the compare you need